# Editor toolbar not working using react plugin react-draft-wysiwyg

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-draft-wysiwyg

The toolbar is not showing all the dropdown when click + the text field is also not showing even I include the css. I am using this plugin react-draft-wysiwyg

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-draft-wysiwyg

[image]

here is the video
https://www.loom.com/share/485fee2f1cf74ed7a37289b074d54139

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from 'react';
import { EditorState, ContentState, convertToRaw, convertFromHTML } from 'draft-js';
import { Editor } from 'react-draft-wysiwyg';
import '../../../node_modules/react-draft-wysiwyg/dist/react-draft-wysiwyg.css';
import draftToHtml from 'draftjs-to-html';
// import htmlToDraft from 'html-to-draftjs';

class DraftEditor extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      editorState: EditorState.createEmpty(),
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    console.log(this.props.defaultValue)
    if (this.props.defaultValue) {
      this.setState({
        editorState: EditorState.createWithContent(
          ContentState.createFromBlockArray(
            convertFromHTML(this.props.defaultValue)
          )
        )
      })
    }
  }

  onEditorStateChange = (editorState) => {
    const html = draftToHtml(convertToRaw(editorState.getCurrentContent()))
    this.setState({ editorState: editorState }, () => {
      this.props.onEditorStateChange(html)
    });
  };

  render() {
    const { editorState } = this.state;
    return (
      <Fragment>
        <Editor
          editorState={editorState}
          toolbarClassName="toolbarClassName"
          wrapperClassName="wrapperClassName"
          editorClassName="editorClassName"
          onEditorStateChange={this.onEditorStateChange}
        />
      </Fragment>
    );
  }
}
export default DraftEditor
```

Package.json

```
{
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.28",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.13.0",
    "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "^0.1.9",
    "availity-reactstrap-validation": "^2.6.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
    "chalk": "^2.4.1",
    "chart.js": "^2.8.0",
    "draft-js": "^0.11.5",
    "draftjs-to-html": "^0.9.1",
    "immutable": "^4.0.0-rc.12",
    "js-cookie": "^2.2.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.15",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.12.0",
    "rc-time-picker": "^3.7.3",
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-bootstrap": "^1.0.0-beta.9",
    "react-chartjs": "^1.2.0",
    "react-chartjs-2": "^2.7.6",
    "react-countup": "^4.2.0",
    "react-data-grid": "^6.1.0",
    "react-datepicker": "^2.8.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
    "react-draft-wysiwyg": "^1.14.5",
    "react-dropzone": "^10.2.2",
    "react-dropzone-uploader": "^2.10.1",
    "react-feather": "^2.0.3",
    "react-fontawesome": "^1.6.1",
    "react-google-charts": "^3.0.14",
    "react-images-upload": "^1.2.7",
    "react-redux": "^7.1.0",
    "react-responsive-modal": "^4.0.1",
    "react-router": "^5.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-router-scroll-4": "^1.0.0-beta.2",
    "react-scripts": "^3.0.1",
    "react-select": "^3.1.0",
    "react-slick": "^0.24.0",
    "react-smart-data-table": "^0.7.1",
    "react-star-rating-component": "^1.4.1",
    "react-switch": "^5.0.1",
    "react-table-6": "^6.11.0",
    "react-tabs": "^3.0.0",
    "react-toastify": "^5.3.2",
    "reactstrap": "^8.0.1",
    "slick-carousel": "^1.8.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "Faker": "^0.7.2"
  }
}
```

Comment: I am not sure why you got the issue, but I simply copy your code and run it on a codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/optimistic-poincare-v2rj5?file=/src/App.js . It's working fine

Comment: i not sure why too. stuck for days

Answer (score 5):

Just Try to remove Strict mode. (If you are running your React App in Strict Mode.)

Comment: It works. React wysiwyg is not being updated and causing some issues.

Comment: solution of the year

Comment: what a life saver